# List possible values for a single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this one

| Value | Role |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 4 |
| B | FD |
| B | XF |

I want to group Role by Value (I don't wanna use the groupby function)

Here are the results I am expecting

| Value | Role |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,4 |
| B | FD,XF |

Can you help me please

Comment: Could you explain why you wish not to use `groupby`?

Comment: Because i don't want the results as a type pandas.Series but as a string